# Java print TreeMap by ordered values

Tags: java, sorting, set, treemap

I'm writing a program that stores data about football teams in nested Tree map. It looks like this:

```
TreeMap<[team name], TreeMap<[team wins], [opponents]>>
```

Where as [team name] and [opponents] are strings and [team wins] is int.
My current aim is to print the data, by team wins in descending order. It has to look like:

```
Liverpool: //map key
wins: <wins>  //nested map key
opponents: <opponents>
```

My thought was to order the nested map entrySet() and then iterate it, while printing data, but I couldn't do that, because from what I read I need TreeSet and map.entry() returns just Set.I need my map to be TreeMap, because when two teams have equal wins, I need to print in alphabetical order. If I was unclear, what is a good way to print a TreeMap, sorted by nested TreeMap key?

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: For the best chance at decent help, please create and post a decent [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read this important link to learn the details.

Comment: At a high level, you would use a List to store the opponents, then call Collections.sort() to sort the list before printing it.

Comment: @PM77-1 My question is how to achieve my goal. Edited my post, hope it's more clear now.

Comment: So currently a team can have multiple values for [team wins], do you want to order by the sum of these values?

Comment: @DaanvanderKallen Each team has one value of wins, the sum of all wins given in the input. A team can have multiple opponents, but I handle that with String opponents to which I append every single opponent. I only need to print my map in the desired order now.

Comment: This doesn't really matter for the answer that I have just posted but if there is only one value for wins that means the TreeMap has only one element, you're datastructure is then unneccessarily complicated. It would be better to use the format `TreeMap<String, Pair<Integer, String>>` then.

Answer (score 1):

TreeMap's ([as the documentation states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)) are naturally sorted by the key that you use. So, if you want to print out data by the number of wins then you need to make the number of wins as your main key.

Since you want your secondary sort to be based on the team name then you would want that to be your secondary key.

Therefore `TreeMap<[wins], TreeMap<[team name], [opponents]>>` would be the correct approach.

Further, since opponents would imply more than one opponent you might want to make it slightly more complicated and change it to the following if needed:

`TreeMap<[wins], TreeMap<[team name], ArrayList<[opponent]>>>`

Hope this points you to the right direction. Do remember that natural ordering in your case would be DESCENDING order for the outer TreeMap i.e. for the `[wins]` so ensure that your Comparable's `compareTo` function does the correct job.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class SO36799415 {

    public static Random random = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> map = new TreeMap(new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                return -Integer.compare(o1, o2);
            }
        });
        int teams = random.nextInt(20) + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < teams; i++) {
            addToMap(map);
        }
        for (Integer wins : map.keySet()) {
            TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>> tmp = map.get(wins);
            for (String team : tmp.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(team);
                System.out.println("Wins: " + wins);
                System.out.println(tmp.get(team));
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void addToMap(TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> map) {
        String name = randomName();
        int wins = random.nextInt(10);
        int opponents = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
        Team team = new Team(name);
        team.setWins(wins);
        for (int i = 0; i < opponents; i++) {
            team.addOpponent(randomName());
        }
        if (map.containsKey(wins)) {
            map.get(wins).put(name, team.opponents);
        } else {
            TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>> tmp = new TreeMap<>();
            tmp.put(name, team.opponents);
            map.put(wins, tmp);
        }
    }

    private static String randomName() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        int len = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            sb.append((char) ('a' + random.nextInt(26)));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static class Team {
        String name;
        ArrayList<String> opponents;
        int wins;

        public Team(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.opponents = new ArrayList<>();
            this.wins = 0;
        }

        public boolean addOpponent(String opponent) {
            return this.opponents.add(opponent);
        }

        public void setWins(int wins) {
            this.wins = wins;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought that too, Unfortunately this solution fails when I have more then one team with equal wins as input.

Comment: It doesn't. What are you talking about? Have you even tried this? Please share your code.

Comment: Well basic java maps, including TreeMap, must have unique keys. If the same key is used as new entry - it simply overwrites it. That was my first attempt and I only ended up with two teams: first with 1 win and second with 0 wins. On the upside it was ordered :D

Comment: I see your problem. Fixing solution. You have to do it a bit differently. You can't just overwrite.

Comment: An easier solution to code (possibly less messy) would have been to just take an array of these 'Teams' that I have created and then just use any stable sort to sort them twice. Once by wins and next by name.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You created these Teams and used Random just to simulate input in my case? Where is the actual adding happening? I I I don't quite understand what this new TreeMap(new Comparator) is and what it is doing.

Comment: The relevant section is just this. `if (map.containsKey(wins)) {map.get(wins).put(name, team.opponents);} else {TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>> tmp = new TreeMap<>();tmp.put(name, team.opponents);map.put(wins, tmp);}` I am assuming opponents don't need sorting. If they do then just sort them at the end or replace that with TreeMap instead of ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a `TreeMap<Integer, String>` called sortedKeys, then you iterate over all the teams of your original KeyMap and add them to sortedKeys using wins as the key and the key in your TreeMap as the value.
You can then just iterate over sortedKeys to get the keys in sorted order and thus you get to your results in sorted order as well.

**EDIT:** Since the keys can't be unique another solution would be to create a TreeSet of pairs with your own comparator that when the keys are equal compares the values instead. You would then get something like this:

```
TreeSet<Pair<String,Pair<Integer,String>>> sortedSet = new TreeSet(new Comparator<Pair<String,Pair<Integer,String>>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Pair<String,Pair<Integer,String>> a, Pair<String,Pair<Integer,String>> b) {
        int res = b.getValue().getKey() - a.getValue().getKey();
        if (res == 0) {
            return a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey());
        } else {
            return res;
        }
    }
});
teams.forEach(new BiConsumer<String,Pair<Integer,String>>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(String k, Pair<Integer,String> v) {
        sortedSet.add(new Pair(k, v));
    }
});
```

I changed your initial datastructure a bit by the way, since you state that teams only have one value for wins that means the nested TreeMap would always only have one entry and thus should just be a pair.

Comment: Well I can also build my nested map this way: TreeMap<[wins], TreeMap<[team], [oponents]>>. The problem as @Sanchit and I discussed above is that you can't have mulitple teams with same wins, because Map keys need to be unique.

Comment: @Alex See my update. Don't blindly replace. Check first.

Comment: Thanks man, Your answer and Sanchit's combined shed some light upon my issue. This looks like a viable solution. I will check it out. Also thanks about the pair. It makes sense not to use map, with only one entry. I will look those pairs up.